# Using Parse.com, do I need to re-download a PFObject each time it's PFRelation is updated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am building a simple messaging app, I have a class called `messageBank` This contains objects with a username field and a PFRelation `receivedMessages`. The `receivedMessages` has pointers to instances of my message class. I am wondering about how to be as efficient as possible when downloading the messages each time (i.e. refresh). I have this code below:

```
- (void)populateMessagesArrayWithCompletionHandler:(userCompletionHandler)handler
{

    //don't want a strong reference cylce so make it equal to a weak destroyable version
    __weak appUser *weakSelf = self;

    PFQuery *messageBankQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"messageBank"];
    [messageBankQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];


    [messageBankQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@" %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            handler(NO, error,NO,NO); //error
        } else {


            self.messageBank = objects[0];
            PFRelation *messagesRelation = [self.messageBank relationForKey:@"receivedMessages"];
            PFQuery *receivedMessagesQuery = [messagesRelation query];
            [receivedMessagesQuery orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];
            [receivedMessagesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                if(!error){

                    [weakSelf.messages addObjectsFromArray:objects];//add messages to array
                    handler(YES, nil,NO,NO);
                }



            }];

        }
    }];
}
```

My question is, each time I want to refresh the messages and check for new ones do I have to fetch the `messageBank` object again? Can I just store the `messageBank` object in the private interface and then do the query on the PFRelation contained in that over and over again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can store it (or the relation if you wanted though this would be a bit weird) and reuse it later.

Note also that if you store it you can use `refreshInBackgroundWithBlock:` to update that object before you use it in the future (if it might have changed contents).

One more note, you can set a limit or a requirement on your relation query so it won't return anything you already have (assuming you know the object id or the creation date of the most recent item you have). In this way you can make the refresh response more efficient.

Comment: I didn't know that about the requirement, thanks. Even if I refresh it it's another API call though right? No matter how I do it it's always going to be two API calls, is that correct? I have to use one call to get the object and I always have to get the object (or refresh it), and then a second call to fetch from the relation right?

Comment: Refresh would be an API call, but you don't need to refresh just to get the relationship to create a query. I was just trying to say that if you store the object you may want to refresh it later before you use it for the other things. The relationship you are already going to explicitly refresh... So if you store the object you only need to make 1 API call to refresh the relationship, and you can add some detail to that request so it doesn't send you data you already have.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your answer. Glad I can do it in one call! cheers